# Escape a double-quote in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I'd want to add this mapping:

```
map <C-K> "_dd
```

How do I escape that double quote so it won't be interpreted as a comment?

Comment: That works fine for me in my .vimrc.  You may however want to restrict it to a specific mode.

Comment: It deletes the line to oblivion. _ register is like /dev/null

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you’ll be fine.

From the manual:

```
                                                        *:quote*
'"' at the start of a line causes the whole line to be ignored.  '"'
after a command causes the rest of the line to be ignored.  This can be used
to add comments.  Example: >
        :set ai         "set 'autoindent' option
It is not possible to add a comment to a shell command ":!cmd" or to the
":map" command and friends, because they see the '"' as part of their
argument.
```

Notice how it says *after* a command — unfortunately, it can be difficult to tell what exactly is meant by the end of the command. Some commands (`:edit`) take only one argument, while others (`:map`, `:help`), can consume everything on the line.

In other words, using `"` after a `:map` should work fine without any special treatment, and I would stick to that as a guideline. If you find that it treats the `"` as the beginning of a comment, just use a backslash: `\"`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess. The issue is probably not with the mapping of a double-quote but the fact that <C-K> is noremapped somewhere else. Run the command :map and see if <C-K> is mapped elsewhere? If it cannot be remapped it will have an asterix.

I know minibufexplor.vim uses <C-K> so that could be your problem?

Hope this helps.